# Fixing validation error for defined schema in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to add a comment API for a user. I defined a different model schema 'userMessages' and used userId as a ref for the schema 'User'. I tried to post the route for comment but getting validation error, even when I have defined userId and Comment String required as true.

This is my schema for userMessages:

```
const userMessages = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
message: { type: String, required: true },

});
```

Here is my controller for adding message:

```
exports.post_comment = (req, res, next) => {

let body = req.body;
body._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

const userId = req.userData.user[0]._id;
body.userId = userId._id;

const commentSchema = new CommentSchema(body);

commentSchema.save()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log('user commented: ', docs);
        res.status(201).json(docs);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    })

}
```

When I try to hit the route userMsg/comment using postman with 'userId and message' as my raw-body parameters, I get the following error:

```
{
"errors": {
    "userId": {
        "message": "Path `userId` is required.",
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `userId` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "userId"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "userId"
    }
},
"_message": "UserMessages validation failed",
"message": "UserMessages validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required.",
"name": "ValidationError"
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem even after defining userID and message as TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in these lines:

```
const userId = req.userData.user[0]._id;
body.userId = userId._id;
```

It should be:

```
const userId = req.userData.user[0]._id;
body.userId = userId;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked! It was very noobie of me to do such error.